# Monaca で　Android 端末からメールが送れない

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

以下のコードで

```
function sendMail() {
    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity (
        {
            action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
            url: 'mailto:メールアドレス'
        },       
        function () {},
        function () {alert ('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
    );
}
```

以下のエラーが出ます。

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webintent' of undefined

Cordovaのwebintentは有効にしてあります。
以下も指定してあります。

```
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
```

何か設定が足りないのかもしれません。
ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: config.xmlに下記を追加して解決しました。
mailtoだったのですね。
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />

Comment: 編集の提案、ありがとうございました。何もかも初心者で申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0):

config.xml に以下を追加することで解決しました。`mail` ではなくて `mailto` でした。

```
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
```

---

*この投稿は質問に追記されていた回答部分を元に個別の回答として投稿しました。*